# Issue with creating HTML list (li) with call back function

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, callback

I am facing this annoying issue with linking the right value to the right row in my HTML list which I am rendering, I think explaining my code would be the best way to explain so here I go.

I have a json string which return data about multiple players from a data base. The players may have multiple entries.

My string is of the form

```
jsonVar = {"someStr":[{"Fbid":"xxxxxxxxx","score":"xxxxxx","game":"x","date":"1300689902"}, .... }]
```

now I want to display the data as a list on HTML for all the columns.

```
createList = function()
{
arrayLength = jsonVar.someStr.length;
for(i=0;i<arrayLength;i++)
{
    listName = document.id('name');
    listScore = document.id('score');
    listGameMode = document.id('gamemode');
    listTime = document.id('time');                             
    listfbID= document.id('fbID');

    fbId = jsonVar.someStr[i].Fbid;

    FB.api('/'+fbId+'/', function(response) 
    {   
         new Element('li',{text: response.first_name +" "+response.middle_name+" "+response.last_name }).inject(listName, 'bottom');        
    });
    new Element('li',{text:jsonVar.someStr[i].Fbid}).inject(listfbID, 'bottom');
    new Element('li',{text: jsonVar.someStr[i].score}).inject(listScore, 'bottom');
    new Element('li',{text:jsonVar.someStr[i].gamemode}).inject(listGameMode, 'bottom');
    new Element('li',{text: jsonVar.someStr[i].date}).inject(listTime, 'bottom');

    }
}
```

The issue would be the name is not correctly returned with the rest of the entries on the list, this I am assuming is due to some delay with with returning of the name from fb.

Comment: You should put all the `new Element(...)` inside the callback of the `FB.api` call (*after the name part*)

Comment: @Gaby but that way i becomes a constant... In the sense, that when the callback is init the loop is already over so i=last value. =/

Comment: posted an answer on how to overcome this (*by using a closure*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a closure so you can pass the current variable to the callback of the api call.

```
FB.api('/'+fbId+'/', ( function() {
    var current_i = i;
    return function(response) 
       {   
         new Element('li',{text: response.first_name +" "+response.middle_name+" "+response.last_name }).inject(listName, 'bottom');        
         new Element('li',{text:jsonVar.someStr[current_i].Fbid}).inject(listfbID, 'bottom');
         new Element('li',{text: jsonVar.someStr[current_i].score}).inject(listScore, 'bottom');
         new Element('li',{text:jsonVar.someStr[current_i].gamemode}).inject(listGameMode, 'bottom');
         new Element('li',{text: jsonVar.someStr[current_i].date}).inject(listTime, 'bottom');
       };
    })() );
```

generic example with closure and ajax callbacks at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/zZ74b/

Comment: Wow, this worked! Thanks, but I don't completely understand how this works... Could you link me to a document that explains what you did here? Thanks...

Comment: @Shouvik, have a look at [MDC - Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) and [Javascript Closures](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/)

Answer (score 1):

You mean UNIX time? Maybe you can use something like this?

```
var newDate = new Date();
newDate.setTime(unix*1000);
dateString = newDate.toUTCString();
```

Where unix is your time.

Comment: Thanks that resolves one of the issues! :) Now for the more complicated of the two. Could you suggest a way I could handle callback?

Comment: You could use JQuery for that. Like $.load('php-script-that-handles-database', your_json_object, function(data) { alert('the php-script answered: ' + data); });
The JSON object will be send as $_POST variable, and you can use json_decode() in PHP for decoding the object.

Comment: I am actually using mootools, Don't wanna mix them up! =)

Comment: Haha, ok ;). Here is some interesting website: http://davidwalsh.name/basic-ajax-requests-mootools. You can use the onComplete event for handling callbacks.

Comment: yeah no, this is the problem... The thing is its a list, and it dynamically grows so sending a i value is really not going to make a difference. Do you get it?

Answer (score 0):

Try This..

```
FB.api('/'+fbId+'/', function(response)
{       
    new Element('li',{text: response.first_name +" "+response.middle_name+" "+response.last_name }).inject(listName, 'bottom');
    new Element('li',{text:jsonVar.someStr[j].Fbid}).inject(listfbID, 'bottom');     
    new Element('li',{text: jsonVar.someStr[j].score}).inject(listScore, 'bottom');     
    new Element('li',{text:jsonVar.someStr[j].gamemode}).inject(listGameMode, 'bottom');     
    new Element('li',{text: jsonVar.someStr[j].date}).inject(listTime, 'bottom');   
    j++;          
});
```

But only if you're sure that the fb API will return the data in the order that you've called for it.

Comment: define j=0, outside the statement

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem arises because FB.api() makes an asynchronous XMLHttpRequest towards Facebook. The callback function you provide will be executed some time later, while your 'for' loop continues to run.

You cannot make FB.api() run synchronously, and you shouldn't do that as well, because it would slow down your list-building extremely, and it would make lots of requests towards Facebook.

IMHO an acceptable solution would be that you store those first, middle and last name fields in your own database, and pass it to the view with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

For the lack of a better solution, this is what I do to solve the issue. I latch it to a unique ID on another column and insert the name by identifying the row. this solution works for me because my number of rows are very small. You may need to rethink the logic if you want to implement it on a larger scale.

```
createList = function() {
arrayLength = jsonVar.someStr.length;
for (i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    listName = document.id('name');
    listScore = document.id('score');
    listGameMode = document.id('gamemode');
    listTime = document.id('time');
    listfbID = document.id('fbID');

    fbId = jsonVar.someStr[i].Fbid;

    new Element('li', {
        text: jsonVar.someStr[i].Fbid
    }).inject(listfbID, 'bottom');
    new Element('li', {
        text: jsonVar.someStr[i].score
    }).inject(listScore, 'bottom');
    new Element('li', {
        text: jsonVar.someStr[i].gamemode
    }).inject(listGameMode, 'bottom');
    new Element('li', {
        text: jsonVar.someStr[i].date
    }).inject(listTime, 'bottom');
    new Element('li', {
        text: "loading"
    }).inject(listName, 'bottom');

    FB.api('/' + fbId + '/', function(response) {
        var connect;
        parent_id = $('fbID');
        child_id = parent_id.getElementsByTagName('li');

        for (j = 0; j < child_id.length; j++) {
            if (response.id == child_id[j].innerHTML) {
                parent_name = $('name');
                child_name = parent_name.getElementsByTagName('li');
                child_name[j].innerHTML = response.first_name + " " + response.middle_name + " " + response.last_name;
            }
        }
    });

}
```

}